# Typescript: How to declare a type of array whose values are equal to keys of object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

how to define `MyInterfaceKeys` in this code?

```
interface MyInterface extends Record<string, any> {
   Appearance?: "default" | "primary" | "link";
   Size?: "small" | "medium" | "large";
   Color?: string;
   Block?: boolean;
}

type MyInterfaceKeys = (keyof MyInterface)[]

// ok => MyInterfaceKeys === ["Block", "Color"] 
// ok => MyInterfaceKeys === ["Appearance"]

// Error => MyInterfaceKeys === ["UnknownKey"]
```

in fact, I want to convert object props to a union literals:

```
type MyInterfaceKeys = ("Appearance" | "Size" | "Color" | "Block")[]
```

Comment: Your code seems to work well - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlSBBABwojijhCQH4AuZAIgBMJ4BXAGzBtkAH3YUowALa10Q0Wz6gA1mwDcJUgGVgALwgt2AZ2l8+c9pIgdgPSeYW0A5hDUbkAYQD2fT1AOGwCRBHdVIPYCgEfloDACNPbxoQUNIAIR8EJTiEviT1AF8iIjB0ajQsHFhECABpCHRDZABeZAAKJXrPGHLsSCqkAEoAbQBdIq4EPloUGB4GMGBPEGQ4Q0NoMDqG1oB9Vgxe3GqtwwHWADdPYA51IlX1qE36w1ahtnTPTLYAGnYvHygbBGA3U9w2J1ebEo1Fo9CQQJBRQA9EjkABRKBQXysAAqpRQAHI2ABVEBKECeADuIC2bAJyGAjQpYBWa2AjhAcFiuWQYE8vPxyAJHXQXR6lTwEAJADo7mtwc9IaTyVSafUEaogA, what's the problem?

Comment: look at the edited

Comment: `keyof MyInterface` is exactly equivalent to the union literal - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlSBBABwojijhCQH4AuZAIgBMJ4BXAGzBtkAH3YUowALa10Q0Wz6gA1mwDcJUgGVgALwgt2AZ2l8+c9pIgdgPSeYW0A5hDUbkAYQD2fT1AOGwCRBHdVIPYCgEfloDACNPbxoQUNIAIR8EJTiEviT1AF8iIjB0ajQsHFhECABpCHRDZABeZAAKJXrPGHLsSCqkAEoAbQBdIpgeBjBgTxBkOENDaDA6hvb6w1YMXtxq1cMB1gA3T2AOQjcFpagwAFUQGZB1hoGC8cmEadn5xeX7x9ak0erFabEo1Fo9CQ9m0ensXh8UHhESifFo9nSnkybGGIwGFzCV2W+0BD1mryI+SAA.

Comment: I found what is the problem, I had this line `extends Record<string, any>` on my interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object types in TypeScript have a set of *known keys*, which correspond to individual string or number [literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) (or symbols); and a set of [*index signature*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) keys, which correspond to multiple possible keys at once (these used to just be `string` or `number`, but now you can use [pattern template literals and symbols in index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures) also).  For example, the following type:

```
type Foo = {
    [k: string]: 0 | 1
    x: 0,
    y: 1
}
```

has two known keys `"x"` and `"y"` and one index signature key `string`.  Your `MyInterface` type has four known keys, but it also has a `string` index signature key (because it extends `Record<string, any>` which has a `string` index signature key).

---

[The `keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) produces the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all the keys.  For `Foo`, that is `"x" | "y" | string`, and for `MyInterface` that is `"Appearance" | "Size" | "Color" | "Block" | string`.

Since every string literal (like `"x"` and `"y"`) is a subtype of `string`, the union of string literal types with `string` is just `string`, and the compiler eagerly reduces it to this.  So `keyof Foo` and `keyof MyInterface` is just `string`.  In some sense, `string` "absorbs" all the string literal keys.

So you cannot use `keyof` to get just the known keys if there are any index signature keys that absorb it.

---

So, what can you do?  The cleanest thing you can do is to consider refactoring your code so that the information you want can be captured more easily:

```
interface MyKnownInterface {
    Appearance?: "default" | "primary" | "link";
    Size?: "small" | "medium" | "large";
    Color?: string;
    Block?: boolean;
}

interface MyInterface extends Record<string, any>, MyKnownInterface { }

type KK = (keyof MyKnownInterface) & string
// type KK = "Appearance" | "Size" | "Color" | "Block"

type MyInterfaceKeys = (keyof MyKnownInterface)[]
// type MyInterfaceKeys = (keyof MyKnownInterface)[]
// type MyInterfaceKeys = ("Appearance" | "Size" | "Color" | "Block")[]
```

Here `MyInterface` is equivalent to what it was before, but `keyof MyKnownInterface` is the union of known keys that you want.

---

You could also use type manipulation to try to tease out the known keys instead of using just `keyof`, although I think all the possible ways I know of have some weird edge cases (I'm about to file a bug having to do with `symbol` keys).  But hopefully you won't run into such edge cases(the `MyInterface` example doesn't).

One way is to use [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to suppress the index signatures, which can be recognized as any key that doesn't require a value even if it's not optional (index signatures represent any number of keys of the right type, including zero such keys):

```
type KnownKeys<T> = keyof {
    [K in keyof T as {} extends { [P in K]: any } ? never : K]: never
}
```

If we do that in your case, you get:

```
type MyInterfaceKeys = (KnownKeys<MyInterface>)[]
// type MyInterfaceKeys = ("Appearance" | "Size" | "Color" | "Block")[]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.4.2#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-UocK-db-ZRdJF9GEk6xdGkLcJK7DetVyj4B0woY2m83Sq3p3S2nB0d2e1Ncm0ZnVZo0mkBmi0y61+5TF0vTD1e8A+wtamsGw0h-xh4LR3JRrqxsjx+aFdsSLboVOWl6Z2wAFU8KHrja+2Bw+uoUF35o3LlMqFEUD5EGMl9wAAUoMe7gxxSAWVAQlAqBAAG4yFARBvjUf6AWQ6BbBWvqahAmaDquVDrpWrYQO4C5djBfbwQO2bDn8Y6RpU44pNOs60vOJboEAA)

Comment: soooo perfect :)))